# VBA Dictionary Array - Multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have basic understanding of VBA, so any help is appreciated. I want to count unique columns a, b, e, and remove the duplicates. columns c, d are to be summarized. The code I have now only works on the first 3 columns (code attached and before and after current macro via images). I am not sure how to add in the additional requirements. Thank you

Before Macro
[image: Before Macro]

After Current Macro
[image: After Current Macro]

```
Sub LineSmasher()
Dim dict As Object, i As Long, dKey As String
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    dKey = (Cells(i, 1) & " " & Cells(i, 2))
    dict(dKey) = Cells(i, 3) + dict(dKey)
Next i
    
Range(Range("A1"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)

For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    dKey = (Cells(i, 1) & " " & Cells(i, 2))
    If Not Cells(i, 3) = dict(dKey) Then Cells(i, 3) = dict(dKey)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need VBA for this. the Excel functions `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` (along with `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` are pretty much all that's needed, where you can sum the filtered data for the summary values

Comment: I suggest first checking the integrity of the data, e.g., Part Number XYZ has two different costs and prices, therefore the expected outcome is unrealistic.

Comment: @Tragamor Appreciate the response. Would rather it be just quick vba button. This data is then going into salesforce. So having vba automatically format (especially by clearing the contents of the sheet, then displaying the dictionary values) would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Scan up the sheet, use the dictionary to reference the row where key first occurred. Summate the values and delete row.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LineSmasher()

    Dim dict As Object, sKey As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngDel As Range
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, n As Long, lastrow As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            sKey = .Cells(i, 1) & " " & .Cells(i, 2)
            If dict.exists(sKey) Then
               r = dict(sKey)
               ' summate
               .Cells(r, "C") = .Cells(r, "C") + .Cells(i, "C")
    
               ' delete later
               If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                   Set rngDel = .Rows(i)
               Else
                   Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, .Rows(i))
               End If
               
               n = n + 1
            Else
               dict.Add sKey, i
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    If rngDel Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No lines deleted", vbExclamation
    Else
        rngDel.Interior.Color = vbRed
        If MsgBox("Delete rows", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            rngDel.Delete
            MsgBox n & " lines deleted", vbInformation
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I need. However, it looks like column D is not being summarized. How can I adjust the code to add in that additional column to be summed. Additionally, if I want to add another column that should have duplicates removed, say columns E, F, G etc.

Comment: Isn't the Cost in Column C ? Add rows under summate `.Cells(r, "D") = .Cells(r, "D") + .Cells(i, "D")` etc

Comment: Yup, and I was able to add additional columns to summate. Thank you so much. There was more thing... I was trying to get one of the columns to concatenate. So if the rows match the key, concatenate all cells in Column XYZ into a single cell. Was trying to add a for each loop but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @90'sProSkater something like `.Cells(r, "X") = .Cells(r, "X") & " " & .Cells(i, "X") & " " & .Cells(i,"Y") & " " & .Cells(i,"Z")` I would guess.